# Referencing a .NET Standard library in an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, .net-standard

I've got a strange issue referencing a net standard application (FW Full 4.5.2)

I got this error `targets 'netstandard2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'.`, wasn't .NET standard supposed to allow references from Core and Framework projects as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated here [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). You need atleast `.NET Framework 4.61` for referencing `.NET Standard 2.0` assemblies.